# php email and phone number validation

Tags: php, validation, email, numbers

I currently have the following working code but I need to build on to this some email and phone number validation to make sure it is an actual email and phone number not other data. I have found code to use

```
function valid_email($email) {
    return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

but I'm unsure how to incorporate this into my current code. I would love some help with this.

This is my current php code

```
//load form validate
$firstName= $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName= $_POST['lastName']; 
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1 ($_POST['password']);
$role = 1;


//prepare input data in an array
$userdata = array($firstName, $lastName, $address, $phoneNumber, $email, $username, $password,$role);


//prepare error list
$errors = array ();

//Validation tests and store list
if ($firstName == "" || $lastName == "" || 
    $address == "" || $phoneNumber == "" || 
    $email == "" || $username == "" || 
    $password == "" || $role == "" ) {
    array_push($errors, "All form fields must be filled out before submitting.");
}

//if errors redirect back to form page and save attempted data.
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['userdata'] = $userdata;
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    header("Location: ../register.php");
}else{
    unset($_SESSION['userdata']);
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO customers (firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, email, username, password) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName', '$address', '$phoneNumber', '$email', '$username', '$password')";

    //die (print_r($query));
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
        $last_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO users_in_roles (userID, roleID) VALUES ('$last_id', 1);";

        if ($mysqli->query($query2)) {
            header("Location: ../Login.php");
        }else {
            die(print_r($mysqli->error));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, you can use the sanitize and validate for the email variable. You should then learn to escape the values before inserting them to you database. 

Remember to use prepared statements

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php || http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php || http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: @Thomas why use regex when there is a function for it built in to PHP? Creating a regex to capture all variations of emails becomes very messy.

Comment: your email validation is ok. To filter phone number use filter_var($mobilenumber, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one example.
I made a foreach with an array just to show you both outputs.

```
$email = ["abc@gmail.com","abc@gmailcom"];
foreach ($email as $e){
    if (filter_var($e, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "valid";
    } else {
        echo "not valid";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/GcKRp

In your case you should probably have it after you check if any of the fields are empty:

```
if ($firstName == "" || $lastName == "" || 
        $address == "" || $phoneNumber == "" || 
        $email == "" || $username == "" || 
        $password == "" || $role == "" ) {
    array_push($errors, "All form fields must be filled out before submitting.");
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    array_push($errors, "Email is not valid.");
}

$phone = "11-331-11111";
$phone = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $phone);
if (strlen($phone) <= 10) { 
    array_push($errors, "Phone not valid.");
}
```

Removes non digits and checks if length is less than or equal to 10.

Comment: ah thanks. I was putting it in the wrong section of my code hence it was not working. What do you use to make a phone number valid?

Comment: @Nicola Let me ask you. How do you know if a phone number is valid? If I give you a phone number, what makes you say this is correct or not correct?

Comment: to make it to have only numbers in the form field and have maximum 10 numbers?

Comment: If that is a valid number for you then see my update. I would never validate phone numbers unless you actually need them. And if I need them I would send an SMS to validate. But that's me...

Comment: the email validation works perfectly, but I'm having trouble getting the phone validation to work

Comment: Sorry about that I changed the code to match your array and such and forgot to remove the !

Comment: @Nicola see here https://3v4l.org/DYiVQ . If my answer has helped and/or solved your problem then feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer.